# Managed Identity fails when running WebApp from Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-vm

I have created a asp.net API that accesses KeyVault to get secrets.

When I run locally on my laptop, I use Managed Identity to access KeyVault with a dedicated Service Princiapl. (with AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and AZURE_TENANT_ID set in my system
environment variables).

This is working just fine.

Now I have created a VM in Azure to be used as a developer machine. All the tools are installed and configured like they are on my laptop.

But when I run the web API I get a 403 telling me the object ID #### does not have Get/List access to KeyVault.
I've checked and the object ID matches the one of the VM. Indeed the VM does not have this access to KeyVault, however I'd expect the Web API to run with the configured AZURE_CLIENT_ID in my environment variables.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure get/list operations are selected/enabled in the [access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad) created for your managed identity/service principal:

[image]

Comment: it is the case already. As I mentioned, it works fine when running the app from my local machine using the managed identity. However when I run it in the VM, I also have to add access policy Get and List to the VM sp, which makes no sense.

Comment: @Sam try disabling the managed identity, reenabling it and reassigning it to the policy.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_bwnozsRHvoGcHZ3&Q_CHL=gl
>